# Java JList model

Tags: java, swing, jlist

How can I make a list model from a `JList` in order to be able to insert an item into it.
I want to use this method: `addElement(java.lang.Object item)`

I found an explanation [here](http://prefuse.org/doc/api/prefuse/data/query/ListModel.html#ListModel()), but the problem is that `ListModel` is an interface 
and even if I write an implementation and override its method, I can't use the `addElement()` method

Comment: Check out this [Sun Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). Contains example on how to add lists to a JList

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java provides implementations of `ListModel` already, like [`DefaultListModel`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html), that you can instantiate and use

For example:

```
final DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
model.addElement("one");
model.addElement("two");
model.addElement("three");

final JList list = new JList(model);
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed the last line to list.setModel(model); and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative method, if someone requires to use a custom `ListModel`. Inside the class that implements the list model interface, it would be necessary to create a structure to actually hold the elements like a `LinkedList`, like this:

```
public class MyListModel implements ListModel{
    
    private LinkedList data;
    private LinkedList<ListDataListener> listeners;

    public MyListModel() {
        data = new LinkedList();
        listeners = new LinkedList();
    }
    
    public void addElement(Object element){
        data.add(element);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getElementAt(int index) {
        return data.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public void addListDataListener(ListDataListener l) {
        listeners.add(l);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeListDataListener(ListDataListener l) {
        listeners.remove(l);
    }
    
}
```

You can also create access methods to do anything related to the `LinkedList`, like `removeElement(Object element)`, or just make the data `LinkedList` public, or use different data structures if necessary. Of course, for a simple implementation it will always be easier to use the models provided with Java.