# Object Array to TextArea

Tags: java, oop, javafx, textarea

I have an array of objects and i want to print them out to a TextArea in a JavaFX program. Im not sure how to go about doing that. Everything that im try doesnt work.

```
for(int i = 0; i < set.getEngCourse().length; i++){
 txt.append(set.getEngCourse()[i]);
 if(i != set.getEngCourse().length -1){
   txt.append("\n");
 }

taken = new TextArea(txt.toString());
```

The object im trying to get onto the TextArea is a couple of course objects.

Comment: Is the `txt` object a `StringBuilder`?

Comment: Just a string. should it be?

Comment: Your code is missing a }

Comment: StringBuilder isnt working with an object array. @Loris Securo I know it is the code editor removed it on here for some reason.

Comment: you can edit your question and add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some assumptions to be made, since not all of the code is posted. We will assume that `set.getEngCourse()` properly returns an array of some Object, and that `set` cannot be null, and that `.getEngCourse()` returns at a minimum an empty array and not a null if there are no courses (if either of these assumptions can be violated, add appropriate null checks). It would be best if the returned array were of some specific type (e.g., `EngCourse`), but the OP code does not make clear what is in the array.

I would approach the solution in a manner similar to the following:

```
StringBuilder txt = new StringBuilder();  // get something to collect the output

for (Object obj : set.getEngCourse) { // If possible, change Object to the specific type
  // add a line break if we have already added something,
  if (txt.length() > 0) {
    txt.append("\n");
  }
  txt.append(String.valueOf(obj)); // will handle null objects
}

taken = new TextArea(txt.toString()); // assumes taken is declared elsewhere
```

If there is a known object type, it would be better to:

- Override the `.toString()` on the object type
- Use the specific object type in the iteration

  ```
  for (EngCourse ec : set.getEngCourse()) {  //use specific type
   ...
   txt.append(ec.toString());  //technically, the .toString() is not needed
  }
  ```

Also, if the `.getEngCourse()` returns multiple objects, I would recommend changing the name to `.getEngCourses()` to make clear that it is returning *N* courses, and not just a single course.

If a `TextArea` is not strictly required, I would also consider using a `JList` or something similar. Basically, dumping everything in to a `TextArea` simply gives output, without much ability to do anything else with it (such as select a particular course for future operations). Consider, e.g., this SO answer [Java JList model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893052/java-jlist-model). In essence *model the domain* using appropriate classes, and then use a model/view/controller approach to display the domain classes rather than thinking of the domain as essentially String objects.

Comment: That wasnt it, but very close. Gave me a good jumping off point. I got it working thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Is your txt object a string? If so then why are you putting a txt.toString in the last line of your snippet?

You can use setText function to display the contents in your text area.

Post the error or problem more specifically and extend your code snippet for us to know the scope of for loop.

Comment: I cant just use the setText. Im trying to get an array of objects onto the textArea. The loop is what i was using to read the array and try to print it to the text area

Comment: What is the type of txt? And what error are you getting?

Comment: NPE at the txt.append(set.getEngCourse()[i]); and i changed it to a StringBuilder